# How to query last records

Tags: mysql, sql

so, if i have this table:

```
    | ID  |   Date   |  Status  |  Value  |

    | 1   | 2-2-2012 |  A       |  5      |
    | 2   | 3-4-2012 |  B       |  3      |
    | 1   | 5-6-2012 |  C       |  1      |
    | 2   | 1-1-2012 |  D       |  4      |
```

and I need to get total value and "most recent" status for every IDs, how to do the query? i tried using group by , but the somehow only oldest status shown in the query result.

I need to get the data became like this:

```
    | ID  |   Date   |  Status  |sum(Value)|

    | 2   | 3-4-2012 |  B       |  7       |
    | 1   | 5-6-2012 |  C       |  6       |
```

i'm a total newbie in this SQL thing, not an IT person, just because my boss ask to extract some data from our database....

thanks in advance...

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `RDBMS` stands for *Relational Database Management System*. `RDBMS is the basis for SQL`, and for all modern database systems like MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, Oracle, MySQL, etc...

Comment: i'm using MySQL and using SQLyog application....

Comment: what is the data type of `date` column?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not mentioned any RDBMs, the query below works on almost all RDBMS.

This uses a subquery which separately gets the latest `date` (*assuming that the data type of date is really stored as `DATE` and not as a string*) for every `ID`. The result of the subquery is then joined back on the table itself in order to get the other columns.

```
SELECT  a.ID, a.Date, a.Status, b.TotalSum
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  ID, MAX(date) max_date, SUM(Value) totalSum
            FROM    tableName
            GROUP   BY ID
        ) b ON  a.ID = b.ID AND
                a.date = b.max_date
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0a3aa/2)

Comment: Please sum up the values as required by OP

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mysql then this will work

```
 SELECT id,date,status,sum(value) 
 FROM (select * from yourTable order by DATE desc ) t  
 group by ID 
 order by ID desc
```

Comment: @JW can you please elaborate why ..? I have experience with oracle an mysql .. and it will work in that ...right .. ?

Comment: you query will not work on Oracle as their have any non-aggregated column that are not added in the `GROUP BY` clause. It will work on MySQL because of [MySQL Extensions to GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-extensions.html)